# Not able to set compile flags in xcode 4.3.3 in build phase/compile sources

Tags: build, compilation, xcode4.3

In Xcode 4.3.3, for some reason, I couldn't set the compile flags for few files that I wanted to skip compiling for ARC.

I basically did Target->Build Phases->Compile Sources, then select the files and hit Enter.

When hit Enter or even just double click on a single file, I don't see a dialog pop up for me to enter the compile flags.

Anyone has the problem? I am using retina Mac Book Pro running on Mac OSX Lion. It somehow doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue and it turns out that the popup shows up out of the XCode window, on the right side of it, pretty far away. You need to slide your XCode window to the left of your screen, hide it under the left corner of your screen, before double clicking on the file compile flags setting.

I have a Retina MBP too, I guess that's the reason. My XCode version is 4.4.1.